# Outlook Calendar Icon Question. Why is there a line through the recurring symbol

Tags: outlook

Why is there a line through the recurring meeting symbol on an outlook calendar event?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means "Exception to recurring item".

http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/icons.htm

Comment: Obviously, you need to look at the specifics to figure out what the exception is.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess my googling skills were lacking yesterday.  I did try, but didn't get results..  #lazyweb

Comment: As a note to what the exception could be. If you edit today's occurrence of a meeting, lets say with an agenda note then it would show that, as today's meeting text is different than the default text used to setup the meeting.

Answer (score -1):

Following a recent Office 365 upgrade, I did not change the individual occurrence in any way from its series...  However, I did notice the day/time of the series in question coincides with another series on my calendar during the same day/time.  Both series have the recurrence symbol with a line going thru it...